# What is the difference between Apache Web Server and Apache HTTPD?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, httpd

I am doing some application monitoring and my requirement is to see what differentiates an Apache Web Server and Apache HTTPD. I know Apache Web Server is a "server" and Apache httpd is a "program".

I need to run both on Linux. Is there any difference in the executable file name or full command line or package name for the two?

Is there any difference in way of deployments?

I have searched online but everywhere Apache Web server and HTTPD are used interchangeably.

Comment: "httpd" is the name of the deamon/service that runs in the background and processes all requests. "Apache Web Server" is the name of the software, which includes httpd.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No difference whatsoever. HTTPD is a program that is (essentially) a program known as [Apache Web server](https://httpd.apache.org).

The only difference I can think of is that on Ubuntu/Debian the binary is called [`apache2`](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) instead of [`httpd`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_confined_services/chap-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server) which is generally what it is referred to as on RedHat/CentOS.

Functionally they are both 100% the same thing.

Comment: Do you know if maybe a few years ago those were two different things?

Comment: @techbum Never. I have been working with Apache servers since 1995 and it is what it is and how I describe.